# Consulta SQL que me traiga el valor que mas se repite y que me realize una subconsulta

Tags: sql, subconsultas

estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que me regrese el valor que mas se repite y que con ese valor haga una subconsulta para extraer informacion de ellos

tengo esta consulta para el valor :

-- • Cuál es el conductor que más comparendos tiene.

```
SELECT nombre, COUNT(nombre) AS Mayor_Comparendos 
FROM ciudadano c,
     comparendo o
WHERE c.id_ciuda= o.ciudadano_id_ciuda
GROUP BY nombre 
ORDER BY Mayor_Comparendos DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

y nesecito hacer que con una subconsulta el valor que me sale pueda extraerle informacion en este caso, que comparendos tiene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendiendo por tu código que trabajas en MySQL, te propongo esta solución:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ciudadano JOIN comparendo
  ON id_ciuda = ciudadano_id_ciuda
  WHERE nombre IN (
    SELECT nombre
      FROM ciudadano JOIN comparendo
      ON id_ciuda = ciudadano_id_ciuda
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING COUNT(*)=(
        SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
            SELECT nombre,
              COUNT(*) n
              FROM ciudadano JOIN comparendo
              ON id_ciuda = ciudadano_id_ciuda
              GROUP BY 1  
          ) c1  
      )  
  );
```

Sin tu dataset voy un poco a ciegas y es complicado que pueda explicarte lo que debes hacer en cada paso pero, a partir de tu intento, parece que buscas lo que te respondo. Prueba y me confirmas.

Comment: Wow, si con esto me pude guiar excelente fue acomodar un par de cosas y ya le pude dar solucion muchas graciass

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes resolver haciendo uso de CTE's:

```sql
WITH ciudadanoconmayorcomparendos
AS
  (
           SELECT   nombre,
                    id_ciuda,
                    count(nombre) AS mayor_comparendos
           FROM     ciudadano c
           JOIN     comparendo o
           ON       c.id_ciuda = o.ciudadano_id_ciuda
           GROUP BY nombre
           ORDER BY mayor_comparendos DESC
           LIMIT    1 ), 
subconsultafinal
AS
  (
         SELECT compare.*
         FROM   ( VALUES row('comparendo1', 'tipoX', 1), 
                         row('comparendo2', 'tipoY', 1), 
                         row('comparendo3', 'tipoY', 2) ) 
         compare(nombrecomparendo, tipo, id_ciudadano )
         JOIN   ciudadanoconmayorcomparendos ciudmay
         ON     compare.id_ciudadano = ciudmay.id_ciuda )

SELECT *
FROM   subconsultafinal
```

El primer CTE (ciudadanoconmayorcomparendos) es una réplica de la subconsulta que ya tienes; por cierto cambié la llamada del where a dos tablas por un JOIN que te da más performance y además agregué el campo id_ciuda (importantísimo).

El último CTE (subConsultaFinal) tiene, primero, una tabla que simula los comparendos que tengas, misma debe tener un campo con id_ciuda (imagino), sino mi pregunta sería ¿cómo piensas hacer el match? ... en fin, luego haces JOIN con tu CTE anterior y tendrías el resultado solo de los comparendos de aquel ciudadano con mayor número de comparendos.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias